# How to add space between events in fullcalendar

Tags: fullcalendar

I want to add space between the rendered events in fullcalendar. So if I have two events on the same day and say their background color is blue i want to add additional white space between them. How can I do that? I haven't been able to find the style to change to accomplish that.

Answer (score 1):

I have recently been working with the fullcalendar for a project of mine and a simple solution to the problem that you are having is to add a white border around each event to get that extra spacing.

Check out http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/eventBorderColor/ for more information. Hope this helps.

Comment: This did get me closer. Thanks

Comment: No worries :) Be good if you could mark this as answered, albeit partly as I am new here :)

Comment: this cannot be a correct solution... What if I want to maintain the bottom border colored as the others?

Answer (score -1):

Just add `margin-bottom` to the event's styling rules. FullCalendar includes margins when positioning events.

CSS:

```
.fc-event {
  margin-bottom: 1px;
}
```

Comment: It does not work because fullCalendar places events with `position:absolute`